# Can the sleep/wake cycle be influenced by non-visible spectrum electro-magnetic radiation?

Tags: human-biology, sleep, circadian-rhythms

I've been reading a few papers on `Melanopsin` and `Suprachiasmatic Nucleus (SCN)`, and see that the sleep/wake transition is influenced and entrained by **visible light, particularly in the blue spectrum** that is registered by special cones in the eye and is transmitted to the SCN.

I've seen a fleeting hypothesis/mention in two of these articles, that electromagnetic radiation may also play a part in the sleep/wake transition and melatonin release, on top of the blue light. It was some time after I read those articles that it dawned on me to ask this question, and I'm unable to find the exact lines where the mention was made.

**Has there been any modern studies on the connection between electro-magnetic radiation (non-visible spectrum) and the human's circadian rhythm entrainment?**

Can humans be affected or feel the influence of electro magnetic radiation at all?

If there is a connection, what is the name of a process/organ/gland by which humans can be affected with electromagnetic radiation?

Thank you for your clarification!

Comment: Maybe this question can be better answered (or is already) at skeptics